# Two-way data bind width of DataGrid column headers

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datagrid

I've got a TreeView with some column headers that are based on a DataGrid. Now, I want to bind the width of those header columns to the width of the columns within the TreeView. An example is below.

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Width="{Binding NameColumnWidth, Mode=TwoWay}" IsReadOnly="True"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Age" Width="{Binding AgeColumnWidth, Mode=TwoWay}" IsReadOnly="True"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Address" Width="{Binding AddressColumnWidth, Mode=TwoWay}" IsReadOnly="True"></DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>

<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding VisibleStudents}">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TreeViewItem ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Classes}">
                <TreeViewItem.Header>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding NameColumnWidth}"></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding AgeColumnWidth}"></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding AddressColumnWidth}"></ColumnDefinition>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        </Border>

                        <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Age}" />
                        </Border>

                        <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Address}" />
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </TreeViewItem.Header>
                <TreeViewItem.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding NameColumnWidth}"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding AgeColumnWidth}"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding AddressColumnWidth}"></ColumnDefinition>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                            </Border>

                            <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Age}" />
                            </Border>
                            <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Address}" />
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </TreeViewItem.ItemTemplate>
            </TreeViewItem>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

When starting the project, I get the following error:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement
>   or FrameworkContentElement for target element.
>   BindingExpression:Path=NameColumnWidth; DataItem=null; target element
>   is 'DataGridTextColumn' (HashCode=38694667); target property is
>   'Width' (type 'DataGridLength')

Comment: Itemsource for datagrid not set?

Comment: No, I'm just hardcoding those values because no data is needed for the DataGrid as I'm only using it for displaying columns.